# ASP.net/MVC file upload with URL rewrite enabled

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, file-upload, url-rewriting

I came across this interesting problem with an ASP.net MVC website, there is an Action method to process uploaded files and it works fine with cassini webserver but when I tried with IIS in my hosting machine the upload fails, after spending lot of time I noticed that it is because of the URL rewite rules inside set to change the incoming URLs to lowercase and add a trailing slash at the end.

Is there any recommendations to avoid problems like this?

Comment: How about changing the rewrite rules?

Comment: Are you sure it is beacause of that? The routing still works correct in MVC with small letter urls and the trailing slash... Is it not some right problem? For example you have no write right to the place where you try to save the uploaded file?

Answer (score 0):

This might sound simple but it would work. Generate your routes so they match your production environment rules. By doing so you'll keep the server from redirecting and causing your issue.